# renaming a specific column of each dataframe in a list as part of a loop

Tags: r

Basically, I would like to create multiple dataframes and attach them to a list (all within a loop) after renaming second columns. Below is the sample code.

the problem is - I want to rename the second column of each dataframe to the loop variable but couldn't manage yet.

```
### create a blank list
temp_list<-vector("list",)

### create a vector with values to use in the loop

temp_years<-c("2010","2011")

### loop to generate the dataframes with name i
##add to the list above, then rename column 2
### of each dataframe to the loop variable (i). 

for (i in temp_years){
  temp_df<-data.frame(coltest11=runif(4),coltest12=runif(4))
  temp_list[[i]]<-temp_df
  names(temp_list[[i]][2])<-i
}
```

desired output in terms of column titles:

```
$`2010`
  coltest11    **2010**
1 0.4781636 0.28835747
2 0.1413173 0.84415993
3 0.6564438 0.01405185
4 0.3046113 0.83951115

$`2011`
  coltest11    **2011**
1 0.8050338 0.2284567
2 0.3049061 0.8308597
3 0.2920562 0.8118845
4 0.3452323 0.9222456
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
### create a blank list
temp_list<-list()

### create a vector with values to use in the loop

temp_years<-c("2010","2011")

#Loop

for (i in temp_years){
  temp_df<-data.frame(coltest11=runif(4),coltest12=runif(4))
  temp_list[[i]]<-temp_df
  names(temp_list[[i]])[2]<-i
}
```

Output:

```
$`2010`
  coltest11      2010
1 0.1481673 0.5234788
2 0.4055919 0.5426163
3 0.2353523 0.5847577
4 0.5258541 0.6792990

$`2011`
  coltest11      2011
1 0.4292431 0.7717647
2 0.2160180 0.4033482
3 0.8142830 0.6944202
4 0.5900886 0.4449840
```

Comment: Am sorry, but what is the difference between your code and OP's code?

Comment: @Onyambu It is OP: `names(temp_list[[i]][2])` and the code in answer is `names(temp_list[[i]])[2]`

Comment: aha. I see what you mean

Comment: that is really cool! thanks a lot! Just so I understand - what exactly is happening when I put the bracket in the wrong place. it doesn't give any error message and behaves like it completed a command/function, however no changes to the data/output.

Comment: @RandyMarsh When you place the bracket as you did you are calling to a vector (in your case a specific column). Instead, `names()` creates a vector of all names and then you can assign other values by indexing positions with `[]`. I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Add `colnames(temp_df)[2] <- i` to your loop

```
temp_list<-vector("list",)
temp_years<-c("2010","2011")

for (i in temp_years){
  temp_df<-data.frame(coltest11=runif(4),coltest12=runif(4))
  colnames(temp_df)[2] <- i
  temp_list[[i]]<-temp_df
  names(temp_list[[i]][2])<-i
}
```